# How to get the identifier of static int of LicenceChecker

Tags: android, string, licensing, android-lvl

When checking the licensing for an application and the 
`public void applicationError(int errorCode)` method returns an int, let's say
`public static final int ERROR_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME = 1;`

I want to display a message showing the "ERROR_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME" part of the int.
The `String error_Code = Integer.toString(errorCode);` will only show "1".

How can I get the string from the int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to generate that, the compiler doesn't keep track of the names of variables.  And that's ignoring things like proguard which intentionally mangle them.  To do that, you either need to use an enum rather than an int, or you need to write a function `String convertErrorCodeToString(int errorCode)` that returns the string

Comment: I had a feeling. It would be good though if we could inform a user why he or she is not allowed / licensed. Thanks

Comment: @Immy You can, it just requires either an enum (enums are strings, with a default value of the enum name) instead of constant ints, or it requires a mapping function.  

Realistically the mapping function is the best anyway if its supposed to be user facing.  A mapping function can do i18n.

Comment: I might try it. Sometimes these not licensed errors come back for no real reason and I was thinking that if something goes wrong with the enum, it would add to the frustration, so if there is an occasional issue, I might just look up the code and deal with the problem accordingly.